# Python - split filename by special character, create folders from filename and move file

Tags: python

I have a folder with the following files:

```
ccd28aab-dacd-45ae-a329-ef3aabfaedb3\1.0.0.0\tenantconfig

714be584-4860-4513-9f22-deb09bd25687\1.0.0.0\tenantconfig
```

I would like to generate 2 folders based on the characters placed before the `\`.

The idea is to generate a script where it creates folders and folder names based on the characters before the backslash and move the file, with the remaining characters as a name, inside the subfolder.

For example create a folder named "ccd28aab-dacd-45ae-a329-ef3aabfaedb3", then another folder inside the previous one, named "1.0.0.0" and finally inside the last folder, move the file having the name of the remaining characters, "tenantconfig".

```
ccd28aab-dacd-45ae-a329-ef3aabfaedb3 (folder)

1.0.0.0 (subfolder)

tenantconfig (file)
```

If it helps, the first part of the filename, the part before backslash will always change (e.g. 714be584-4860-4513-9f22-deb09bd25687), but the last 2 parts (the subfolder and file names) will always remain the same.

Comment: Please don't use non-relevant tags (or explain how they are relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Python script that you can use to create the folders and move the files:

```
import os
import shutil

# Define the source directory containing the files
source_directory = "/path/to/source/directory"

# Iterate through all files in the source directory
for filename in os.listdir(source_directory):
    # Split the filename into parts using the backslash as a separator
    parts = filename.split('\\')

    # Ensure that the filename has at least two parts (folder and file)
    if len(parts) >= 2:
        folder_name = parts[0]  # The part before the backslash
        subfolder_name = parts[1]  # The part after the first backslash
        file_name = parts[-1]  # The part after the last backslash

        # Construct the full paths
        folder_path = os.path.join(source_directory, folder_name)
        subfolder_path = os.path.join(folder_path, subfolder_name)
        file_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, file_name)

        # Create the folder structure if it doesn't exist
        os.makedirs(subfolder_path, exist_ok=True)

        # Move the file to its new location
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source_directory, filename), file_path)

print("Files have been organized.")
```

This script first gets the path to the folder containing the files. Then, it gets a list of all the files in the folder. For each file, it splits the file name into two parts: the part before the backslash and the part after the backslash. It then creates the parent folder and the subfolder. Finally, it moves the file to the subfolder.

This script will create the folders and move the files for you.

Comment: The script is almost there, I have just noticed that the filename remains the same (e.g. ccd28aab-dacd-45ae-a329-ef3aabfaedb3\1.0.0.0\tenantconfig) instead of being renamed to "tenantconfig".

Comment: Change the Code As per your requirement, I hope this helps